# Python: Enumerate lines in txt file followed by comma

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a text file that contains comma delimited coordinates as floats in the following format.

```
0.5,0.8,1.0
0.6,0.9,1.2
```

I need to enumerate each line within the text file for which I have read the file and prepended a count to each line using the following.

```
infile = open('coordinates.txt', 'r')
line = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
count = ['%d %s' % (i, line) for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1)]
numbered_coordinates = open('coordinates.txt', 'w')
numbered_coordinates.writelines(str("".join(count)))
numbered_coordinates.close()
```

Which outputs the following.

```
1 0.5,0.8,1.0
2 0.6,0.9,1.2
```

However, I require a comma after each number in the count, I have tried inserting a comma to the count parenthesis and by adding it as a string when writing the file.

```
numbered_coordinates.writelines(str(",".join(count)))
count = ['%d %s' % (i, line) + ', for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1)]
```

Which gives.

```
,1  0.5,0.8,1.0
,2 0.6,0.9,1.2
```

Seems simple enough but has cost me consdiderable time!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what output you are trying to get but if u desire this output:

```
1,0.5,0.8,1.0
2,0.6,0.9,1.2
```

than simply change

```
count = ['%d %s' % (i, line) for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1)]
```

to

```
count = ['%d,%s' % (i, line) for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1)]
```